# Undefined parameter after function call, only on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have an error thar weirdly appears only on Safari (testing on Version 14.0.3): I have a function call with a string parameter (named value below) that becomes undefined once ine the function. I never developped on Safari before so maybe there are some things that I'm not aware of?

```
console.log(`value=${value}`); // value=something
const valueJT = await this._asyncBeautify(attr, value, false, CollUtil.TransMode.ALL, CollUtil.TagsMode.NONE);

...

async _asyncBeautify(attributeName, value, flatten = false, transMode = CollUtil.TransMode.NONE, display = CollUtil.TagsMode.NONE) {
console.log(`value=${value}`); // value=undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

Check whether there is a `var` declaration with the same name as the `value` parameter somewhere in the function body (UglifyJS often does this when minifying code). There is a known issue in WebKit where [variables with the same name as a parameter are incorrectly hoisted](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=223533).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which I solved by changing the default setting:

```
UglifyJS.minify(code, {
    /**
     * Due to problems with selecting variable names in build files,
     * include this option.
     * ==> merge_vars (default: true) — combine and reuse variables
     */
    compress: {
        merge_vars: false
    },
});
```

Compress options: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS?tab=readme-ov-file#compress-options

Bug description: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/issues/5818

EDIT:
There is another option - flag `webkit: true`:

```
UglifyJS.minify(code, {
    webkit: true
});
```